# missing files after git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

Some weeks ago I create a feature branch, I'm developing in. There are severals commits and some new files as well. I can change from master branch to my development branch and versa vice and everything is fine.

Today I tried to merge my branch back to the master branch. Therefore I changed to master and called

```
git merge mydevbranch
```

which resulted in several merge conflicts. i resolved these conflicts with

```
git mergetool
```

But now, I realized, there are some files missing within the result I have to commit.
So there are two questions: Shouldn't be there all merged items on my hard disk after merging? How can I proceed to get the real merge result (master + my feature branch).

Comment: if there is file present in mydevbranch missing in master, that means you probably removed them in one of the branch and selected the wrong one to keep

Comment: the file is new in devbranch

Comment: does `git log --pretty=oneline --stat --all path/to/missing/files` give you interesting output ? Also, are you sure you "git add && git commit" them? If you checkout to the dev branch, does the files there again ?

Comment: yes, when i checkout the dev branch, all files are there. So the commit there should be correct

Comment: does `git show HEAD --stat` display theses files as deleted ?

Comment: After some investigation I found the following. 
The file was added by me on master before creating the branch (that's why it was in my dev-branch). But now the crazy thing: The file was deleted in master afterwards by a colleague, but without any status information. Status log only shows the creation of the file.
So the merge was correct, but due to the missing status information it was not comprehensible to me.

Comment: @Asenar's `git log --pretty=oneline --stat --all path/to/missing/files` helped me find that I was mistaken about what was happening in my branch history. I'd looked at some other posts and human error seems a common cause of variations of this issue. This was the tool I needed to find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: Shouldn't be there all merged items on my hard disk after merging?

I do a experiment on my own environment. It has the same effect as you has. So my conclusion is that, the file deleted in your master branch will not come back in your master branch if you merge the develop branch which has that same file.

I think this makes sense. Let's assume that you had deleted lots of unwanted files in the master branch and commit those removals. Then you merge the develop branch who has all those unwanted files. If all those unwanted files are 'added' into the master branch again, you may be upset to see that happen because you have to take time to delete them again.

Answer (score 6):

After some investigation I found the following. The file was added by me on master before creating the branch (that's why it was in my dev-branch). But now the crazy thing: The file was deleted in master afterwards by a colleague, but without any status information. Status log only shows the creation of the file. So the merge was correct, but due to the missing status information it was not comprehensible to me.

Comment: I experienced similar thing. How is it possible? Would you want to post another question with detailed info for someone to take a look?

Answer (score 3):

Check if there is nothing in stash

```
git stash pop
```

For new files, please make sure you add them first (git status should list them)

```
git add
```

The best docs about Git at all, including branches: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: there is nothing in stash. the file is commited for some weeks within the dev branch and I already read the whole section of the book. but with no success. 
I switch to master, call the merge command and there are some files missing. I won't commit as long as there are not all files present (this seems to be right to me).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to lose files that way.

You may try this alternative:

```
git checkout mydevbranch
# following command to find the previous state easier if you are not familiar with reflog
git branch tmp-checkpoint 
git rebase master
```

Then solve conflicts. If the files are still missing, you can use git bisect (see man page) to find the point where they disappear

Comment: This approach contains the command syntax needed to resolve the problem.